# rabbitmq pika python on an interrupt, finish currently fetched process and then stop consuming new requests

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am starting multiple instances of the rabbitmq consumer(same queue) through a single process(multiprocessing). On an interrupt, I want all the consumers to gracefully shutdown. By that I mean, in case a process fetched from queue is already running, let it finish and then stop consuming any more requests and stop the queue.

Is there a way of knowing if queue is executing something and then wait for it to finish and then stop the queue?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of knowing if queue is executing something and then wait for it to finish and then stop the queue?

No, there is no way to know this. You should be using message acknowledgements. When you wish to stop consuming, you can call [`basic_cancel`](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/0.12.0/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.py#L286-L287) and then exit that consumer process. RabbitMQ will only consider those messages as acknowledged as delivered, so you won't have to worry about losing a message.